# what's the difference between decodeRuneInternal and decodeRuneInStringInternal

Tags: go

In golang's std package, "func decodeRuneInternal" and "func decodeRuneInStringInternal" are the same except the args, that is:

```
func decodeRuneInternal(p []byte) (r rune, size int, short bool)
func decodeRuneInStringInternal(s string) (r rune, size int, short bool)
```

Why not just define decodeRuneInStringInternal as:

```
func decodeRuneInStringInternal(s string) (r rune, size int, short bool) {
    return decodeRuneInternal([]byte(s)) (r rune, size int, short bool)
}
```

in utf8.go, decodeRuneInStringInternal's  implementations is the same with decodeRuneInternal.

WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions avoid the memory allocation in the conversion `[]byte(s)` in the case where the string function wraps the []byte function or the memory allocation in the conversion `string(p)` in the case where the []byte function wraps the string function.